# One Pass Model Tree Hierarchy Creation with a C# target

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

In short, I'm wondering how to properly build model hierarchies from within an ANTLR grammar in one pass and what the proper way to do that is with the current C# code generation. Accessing return variables does not currently seem to work, as described in the docs.

See this example from the documentation

```
field
    : d=decl ';' {System.out.println("type "+$d.type+", vars="+$d.vars);}
    ;
decl returns [String type, List vars]
    : t=type ids+=ID (',' ids+=ID)* {$type = $t.text; $vars = $ids;}
    ;
```

My implementation is in C#, but the [C# target documentation](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target) (circa 2008?) doesn't mention any deviations from the standard action pattern within grammars. I'm using ANTLRWorks 1.4 (not the latest 1.4.2 as of this writing) due to [this](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target?focusedCommentId=25559049#comment-25559049). My implementation, which basically populates a 1 deep tree hierarchy with nested innerStats:

```
alias returns [IStatement alias]
    // Alias(string identifier, List<Statement> value, StatementType statementType, MetaData metaData)
    @init { List<IStatement> innerList = new List<IStatement>(); }
    :   ^(ALIAS ID ( id=innerStat{if($id != null) {innerList.Add($id.myInnerStat);}} )+ ) {$alias = new Alias($ID.ToString(), innerList , StatementType.Alias, null) as IStatement; }
    ;

innerStat returns [IStatement myInnerStat]
    :   s=simpleAlias { myInnerStat = $s; }
    |   s=simpleBind { myInnerStat = $s; }
    |   s=command { myInnerStat = $s; }
    |   increment { myInnerStat = null; }
    |   s=exec { myInnerStat = $s; }
    ;

simpleAlias returns [IStatement myAlias]
    // Alias(string identifier, List<Statement> value, StatementType statementType, MetaData metaData)
    @init{ myAlias= null; string id1 = null; string id2 = null; }
    @after{ myAlias = (new Alias(id1, id2, StatementType.Alias, null)) as IStatement; }
    :   ^(ALIAS ID) { id1 = $ID.ToString(); }
    |   ^(ALIAS i1=ID i2=ID) { id1 = $i1.ToString(); id2 = $i2.ToString(); }
    ;
```

This returns the following errors:

```
error(117): D:/Files/.../SourceEval.g:39:29: missing attribute access on rule scope: id
error(117): D:/Files/.../SourceEval.g:43:18: missing attribute access on rule scope: s
error(117): D:/Files/.../SourceEval.g:44:17: missing attribute access on rule scope: s
error(117): D:/Files/.../SourceEval.g:45:14: missing attribute access on rule scope: s
error(117): D:/Files/.../SourceEval.g:47:11: missing attribute access on rule scope: s
```

Currently, the only way I see to around this problem is to create a method within my C# model and then call `Model.Aliases.Last().AddChild(IStatement)` from within innerStat, which breaks encapsulation. Thanks for any help.

edit: The corrected code can be found here: https://github.com/keithharvey/Script-Parser/blob/master/Installer/Model/DAL/SourceExpr.g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how the examples always refer to an attribute of a rule:

```
$d.type
$d.vars
$t.text
```

except the `$ids`, but that one isn't a rule because the `+=` makes it a `List`.

Your code has 5 illegal usages of rule attributes (or the absence of them):

### 1

`$id != null` is invalid because you didn't use an attribute at all, try: `$id.myInnerStat != null` instead.

### 2

`s=exec { myInnerStat = $s; }` is wrong because you didn't use an attribute at all, you need to access an attribute of `exec` (you didn't post that rule, so I don't know what).

### 3, 4, 5

`$ID.ToString()`, `$i1.ToString()` and `$i2.ToString()` are wrong, `ToString()` isn't an valid attribute of `ID`. Try `$ID.text`, etc. instead.

Comment: Thanks man, I was in confused magic land for too long. It's weird 3,4 and 5 weren't throwing errors. I'll post the corrected code.

Comment: @Daniel, interesting. Perhaps the C# target accepts `ToString()`, but the Java target does not (accept `toString()`). Using the `.text` attribute makes the grammar more portable since it works with all language targets (or at least: should work! :)).